# Amazon Linux AMI - Upgrade OPenssh version

Tags: amazon-ec2, openssh, amazon-ami

I am using a Amazon Linux AMI base ec2 instance. The current openssh version on the instance is 
OpenSSH_6.2p2

Question is how to upgrade it to openssh 6.4.

I was searching  it and could not find the answer

Answer (score -2):

An updated openssh package is available in the Amazon Linux AMI repositories. This update adds fixes for `CVE-2014-2653 and CVE-2014-2532`. To install the update run:

```
sudo yum install openssh
```